# Custom attributes for flat file authentication in CAS

Tags: java, cas

I am an absolute novice in this entire stack so I apologize in advance if this is a very dumb question.

I'm working on setting up a local (mock) CAS service so we're able to test our apps against an auth system which at least remotely resembles something we have on our staging/production environments.

I'm using https://github.com/ubc/vagrant-cas as a starting point. I've managed to set up this by modifying `cas.properties` and `deployerConfigContext.xml` to enable me to actually pass custom attributes when a user signs in. i.e.

```
<bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao">
    <property name="backingMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
            <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" />
            <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
            <entry key="puid" value="12345678910" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This combined with the default `org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler"` means that whenever I sign in with a username and password that is identical (i.e. username 'admin' password 'admin' ) then that user is signed in and the attribute `puid` is returned with the value of '12345678910' (this same PUID is returned for every username/password combo).

(I had to enable the attributes to be sent back in the 'Services Management' app)

What I *actually* need is to be able to have multiple users, all with different puid values. i.e.

username:password:1234

username2:password2:5678

etc.

I've noticed there is a `org.jasig.cas.adaptors.generic.FileAuthenticationHandler` but that only allows for username::password and no custom attributes. (so near yet so far).

I'm way out of my depth, I'm not a java programmer and have hit the limit of my google-fu. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Additionally, it doesn't need to be a flat file. I'm happy hardcoding username/password/custom-attributes in an xml file somewhere. Whatever works and is easiest.

Comment: I am assuming you are using CAS 3. file-based authn as you discovered does not yet support custom attributes. You may be interested in this https://github.com/Unicon/cas-addons/wiki/Configuring-JSON-ComplexStubPersonAttributeDao

Comment: Also note that CAS 3 is EOLed.

Comment: Thanks @MisaghMoayyed! Sadly I don't have any control over which version of CAS we use, so I'm stuck with 3 for now. I should have noted that in the question. I'll take a look at the cas-addons repo and see if I can get something going.

Comment: Hey @MisaghMoayyed do you want to put the link to the cas-addons into an answer? I'll accept it then. I managed to get it working and got it merged it into the Vagrant CAS repo mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File-based authn does not support custom attributes. You may be interested in this: https://github.com/Unicon/cas-addons/wiki/Configuring-JSON-ComplexStubPersonAttributeDao

Comment: I've accepted this as the correct answer as it got me to where I needed to. Take a look at the repo linked in the question to see a working example.